# Php Post method does not enter condition

Tags: php, post, methods

Firstly my english is very bad, sorry. I'm trying to write blog in PHP. I am writing login.php. But POST method is not connected.

I write kullanici adi and sifre says:

> Kullanıcı adı ve Sifre bos birakilamaz.

It's not syntax problem. I am using datagrip for database.
PROBLEM  `if($_POST)` --> Can not read it from here

```
<?php
if($_SESSION["login"]) // üye giris yaptımı yapmadımı session login kullanıcı girisi yapılmıssa gösterilir
{
require_once "inc/default.php";

}else {

    if($_POST)
    {

        $kadi = p("kadi"); // wherein p function
        $sifre = p("sifre");

        if(!$kadi || !$sifre){
            echo "Kullanıcı adı ve Sifre bos birakilamaz.";
        }
        else{
            $query = query("SELECT * FROM uyeler WHERE uye_kadi = '$kadi' &&  uye_sifre='$sifre' && uye_rutbe = 1");
            if(mysql_affected_rows()) // etkilenen satır varmı
            {
                $row = row($query); // row fonksiyonu çağrılır
                $session = array( // sessionlar oluşturulur.
                    "uye_id" => $row["uye_id"],
                    "uye_rutbe" => $row["uye_rutbe"],
                    "uye_kadi" => $row["uye_kadi"]
                );
                session_olustur($session);

                go(URL."/admin");
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<font color='red> Böyle bir Teknovol yöneticisi bulunmamaktadır.</font>";
            }
        }



    }
```

## HTML :

```
<div id="giris_yap">
        <form action="" method="POST">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Kullanıcı Adı : </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="kadi"/></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Şifre : </td>
                <td><input type="password" name="sifre"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><button type="submit"> Giriş yap</button> </td>
            </tr>


        </table>
        </form>
    </div>


    <?php

}
```

?>

## p function :

```
function p($par,$st = false)
{
if($st)
{


    return htmlspeacialchars(addslashes(trim($_POST[$par])));

}
else
{
    return addslashes(trim($_POST[$par]));
}
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: When do you ever need `addslashes`?

Comment: i m using for security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error here:

```
$query = query("SELECT * FROM ...
```

It should be:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ...
```

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
Add error checking, such as `or die(mysql_error())` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

---

**Important Notes**

Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

[Your script might be at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)